# Need a conclusive answer re: WCF UriTemplate constraints

Tags: wcf, rest, client

WCF REST -->Client<-- (not a service)

Unfortunately, I am forced into a situation where I need to make calls against URIs that do not comply with the 'name=value' standard.

Basically, I need to (GET)...

```
http://host/resource/method/?filter=some.thing={value}
```

...which has compound values.

This translates instead of a 'name=value' pair to 'name=value=value' token, which does not correspond to RFC 6570 and is rejected by the WCF UriTemplate class.

I'm already using several (client) WCF extensibility points, but I'm not enough of a black-belt to know precisely whether or not its possible to make a call such as the one noted above, and if so: where do I inject it?

Attempts to URL encode my way around this thus far have not worked (the server ignores my client query).

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm banging my head against the wall with this.

The error of course is:

"The UriTemplate '?filter=some.thing={value}' is not valid; each portion of the query string must be of the form 'name=value', when value cannot be a compound segment. See the documentation for UriTemplate for more details."

I hope folks like Carlos Figueira are watching... :)

Warmest regards